# just wanna highlight some texts when use a browser to view local html

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, edit

A lot of tutorials which can be downloaded have the file type of `.chm`, `.pdf`, `.html`, etc. I downloaded a Java SE tutorial of Java SE in HTML format. When I use chrome to view it and everything is good. But  I just wonder how could I just directly highlight some useful information (e.g. text) when I use chrome to view it? The html files are local, I know that I could use some software to edit it, like using HTML tag `<font color:>` etc.

But I just want to highlight it directly in the browser like editing it in word. Is there any suggestion? Dose chrome support such kind of plugin? If you still don't understand what i mean, please refer to "clip to evernote", which is a plugin of chrome and can cut the pages and upload them to the evernote server. when I use evernote client to read them, I can directly highlight some words which is useful to me.

Comment: Have you ever tried pressing ctrl+f? Plus, this question isn't about programming.

Comment: yeah, i know, but I have no choice.. ctrl+f is the finding function. I don't understand why you ask me to try that?

Comment: Because that's what I make out from your question. And yes, you DO have a choice. Try SuperUser. This question is offtopic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I DO NOT just want to find the key words in the whole page. I want to highlight it, like set them as red, give them a underline etc. Anyway, thanks. If this topic is not suitable on StackOverflow, I will delete it.

Comment: Use ctrl+f in Opera then. Opera highlights all matches.

Comment: So, did you try the Amaya browser editor ?

Answer (score 0):

It's much more a SuperUser question, but ... There is a lot of plugins for highlighting web pages out there. <del>You could try Yawas or [Simple Highlighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hljnlfolmbmibdjaikiaepgepgnldclj?hl=en-GB)</del>

**edit:** ok, I think I understood better your problem ... Yawas, Simple Highlighter, as well as most other highlighters, don't hightlight on local pages.

I'm not sure there is such an highlighter available for Chrome, then. What I would suggest is to try opening you documentations with [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/) instead of Chrome. It's both the Browser and the Editor from the W3C; and since it has both functionalities, you probably will be able to do what you want on your local pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to your computer by clicking "Open a new tab containing a list of highlights and notes on just this page".  Then you can save only the html contents to your computer with the name as you like. Don't try to use ALT to save the list of note because you will never see the contents what you want to save.